# How to get the details of a proof right during a exam?

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question

#### About me

I'm a computer science student, about to graduate. If everything works out as planned, I am going to do a cs master's program. I'm really into maths and theoretical cs, and therefore, I took any class related to these topics I could.

#### Question

Although, I'm able to learn the topics of a class very well, I fail in written exams, because I miss out on details that are important. I know what the details are, and why they are needed, but in an exam situation, I'm missing out on these, which leads to the failing the test, or a bad grade. In an oral exam situation I tend to be far better, which kind of strengthens the point of me learning well enough.

For my last exam prep, I tried to write as many proofs as possible, to get some sort of automation to it, but that didn't work out in the test later.

Is there a secret trick I don't know or any other advice that you could give me, to get proof writing in exams right?

Comment: No magic, just practice. No two proofs of different theorems use the same strategies always.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this question violating any rules?

Comment: @SeanRoberson I guess proofs that use PigeonHole principle, induction or reductions use the same principles?

Comment: "Questions about choosing a course, academic program, career path, etc. are off-topic [...]"...My question isn't about any of those. I can't understand why it has been closed.

Comment: The question has been closed because you are asking for personal advice, i.e. you are asking for recommendations regarding how to prepare for exams.  This falls under the "etc." of the canned close reason.  It may also be worth mentioning that your question isn't really about mathematics---it is about strategies for studying for mathematics examinations.  As such, the question is not really on-topic here.  Such a question *might* be on-topic on the Math Educators SE.